# Create a DVD Video ISO image from a directory

Tags: iso, dvd

I've prepared myself a DVD Video image using 3rd-party tools. It has created a `VIDEO_TS` folder et al, and looks great.

What I'd like to do next is to add another folder to store additional non-DVD-video content alongside the DVD. The goal is that the DVD will play without any issues on consumer DVD players, but if inserted into a computer and "browsed," there will be an additional folder there containing pictures and whatever else I'd like to put there.

How can I build a DVD-Video compatible ISO image from an existing folder structure? I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: If you simply wanted to create an ISO image from a VIDEO_TS directory structure, [K9Copy](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/K9Copy) might be a good choice. It's a powerful graphical tool which supports those kinds of conversions and it's available for Ubuntu (multiverse).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to add additional graft points for the data directories you want to add in.

#### Example

```
$ mkisofs -dvd-video -o my_video_dvd.iso -V "DISC_LABEL" \ 
   -graft-points \
       "/AUDIO_TS=/media/cdrecorder/AUDIO_TS" \
       "/VIDEO_TS=/media/cdrecorder/VIDEO_TS" \
       "/DATA=/somedir/with/data"
```

The left side of the equals is the directory where it will show up on the DVD, the right side is the path where the content is coming from for the compilation.